# Prefijos en IE y Safari

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un inmenso problema, estoy usando prefijos para que mi pagina se vea bien en los distintos navegadores, almenos en algunos, pero estos prefijos parecen no servir, estoy checando en IE y Safari y se ve mal [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`.nav{ -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly}`
Pero aun asi no se arregla, alguien podria ayudarme? gracias

```
.nav {    /*Contenedor de la navegacion*/
            display: flex;
            height: 7rem;
            background-color: white
        } 

        .logo { /*Contenedor del logo*/
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 20%;        
        } 

        .elementos-nav {    /*Contenedor de los enlaces*/
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            list-style: none;
            -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            width: 80%;
            align-items: center;  
            padding: 0;
        }

        .elementos-nav a { /*Diseño de los enlaces del NAV*/
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            transition: all .7s;
            font-size: calc(1em + 2vw)          
        }
```

Comment: Muéstranos tu código

Comment: Listo ya puse el codigo

Comment: Estás seguro que `-ms-flex-pack` soporta el valor `space-evenly`? Revisa https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#justify-content-property